# Nuxt: Script is not run when changing the router

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-meta

I have a page with a dynamic router, for example, a product in store. With the help of asyncData comes a script (for example, alert(1)) that I embed on the page using the head function.

```js
private head() {
  return {
    script: [
     "innerHTML": "alert(1)"
    ]
  }
}
```

But when changing the router to the same type of page (switching between products), the script is not executed again.
How can this be solved?
I want the script to be executed on every visit to the page.

Comment: Where is this code even written? Why don't you use `mounted()`, `asyncData()` or any regular hooks?

Comment: In mounted() hook http://joxi.ru/DmBaYBFqgRglrP?d=1 it work only first load.
But if I change route to other product http://joxi.ru/bmoGK1cO7DO8my?d=1 .
New tag add, old tag not remove and new script not run.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to show here. Please be more explicit and edit your actual question.

Comment: You should take a look at the [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). `beforeRouteUpdate` should be used instead of `head()`

Comment: Is it your final goal to execute a script that comes as an string from your api in your asyncData method? Does this script need to run only on the client side?